# Error when trying to get activity context

Tags: java, android, android-context

I can't get the context of my activity for some reason. **Note -** It was working before but now Android Studio shows an error but does not stop my app compiling and running as expected. I've added my code further down but ultimately I think the problem is somewhere else because if I try to get the activity context in a new, empty activity, I get an error.

```
package com.example.myapp

public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
        Context context = this; // Error here
    }
}
```

The error is:

```
Incompatible types.
Required: android.content.Context
Found: com.example.myapp.TestActivity
```

This error only happens for this project. My searches for an answer have yielded no positive results. In fact I can't find anything on the exact issue I'm facing.
What I have tried to fix this:

1. `this` instead of `MainActivity.this` - same error as above
2. `getApplicationContext()` - cannot resolve method error
3. `getActivity().getApplicationContext()` - same error as #2
4. Clean & Rebuild project / Sync Project with Gradle Files
5. Restarting Android Studio
6. Android Studio versions 2.3.3 & 3.0 - same issue

I'm new to Android development so if you have a solution for me, please phrase it as simply as possible. Thanks in advance. Here is my code - I get the error in the `onClick` method where it says `MainActivity.this`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Find the View that shows the Numbers category
        TextView numbers = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.numbers);

        // If View is present, set a click listener on that View
        if(numbers != null) {
            numbers.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent numbersIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NumbersActivity.class);
                    startActivity(numbersIntent);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't see anything wrong in your code...and I haven't downvoted

Comment: There's no `TestActivity` in your code, nor any `Context context = this`?

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. TestActivity was just a brief test to see if getting the context would work without any of my other code.

Comment: So what's the actual error you get now? And on which line?

Comment: try to use MainActivity.class at the creation of the intent.

Comment: @billynomates Where it says `MainActivity.this`

Comment: @Ivan Thanks but that doesn't work.

Comment: It's not possible. I just ran your code and it works fine. Make sure the code above is exactly what you have in Android Studio. Also restart Android Studio just in case.

Comment: @billynomates Okay I'll try doing that again. Yeah like I said the app still compiles and runs as expected. Maybe it's just an Android Studio issue.

Comment: Can someone also point out why I got downvotes for my question with no explanations? It would be much appreciated.

Comment: If it doesn't crash your app, it's just an error with Android Studio. I can't explain the downvotes - seems like someone is aggressively downvoting all new questions 

Comment: @billynomates Restarted everything and still getting the error. Not getting the error in other Android Studio projects I have. Thanks for your help.

Comment: please check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution and that was to add `google()` to my project's build.gradle file like so:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}
```

I also deleted the project and cloned it again so it could build from scratch. Not sure whether that helped or not.